# How to handle a legacy database in the Django framework

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, web

I'm working on an Django app that needs to access a very large (MySQL) database, the db has no foreign keys whatsoever. I need to do queries on multiple tables. The way I'm doing it is VERY inefficient and involves doing multiple loops:

```
{% for flower in especies_id %}
    <td>{{flower.especies}}</td>
    {% for family in family_id %}
        {% if family.family_id == flower.family_id %}
                <td><a class="nav-item active" href="/home">
                {{family.family_name}}</td></a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to handle this db with the Django shell maybe JavaScript? Or refactor the db entirely?

(edit):
the db has ~3000 entries
relationship between two tables are made using an additional one:
**flower2estate** which contains estate_id, flower_id

Models.py:

```
    class Listflower(models.Model):
       
        especies_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        family_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        especies = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        
    
        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'listflower'

class Estate(models.Model):
    estate_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    estate_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'estates'

class Flower2Estate(models.Model):
        estate_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        especies_id = models.IntegerField()
    
        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'flower2estate'
            unique_together = (('estado_id', 'especie_id'),)
```

Views.py:

```
def flowers(request):
    list_flower = ListFlower.objects.all().order_by('especies_id')
    paginator = Paginator(list_flower, 3)
    page = request.GET.get("page")
    try:
        flowers = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        flowers = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        flowers= paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'accounts/flowers.html', {'page':page,"flowers"
```

:flowers,"especies_id":flowers})

I need to get the "flower" and the corresponding "estate" without the need to loop between 3000 entries.

Comment: Please show your models and your view. How big are the lists you’re looping through?

Comment: Sure, maybe, depends! We need to know more about what you're working with in order to say. Django can usually deal, but it might not be easy.

Comment: added an edit with the information, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some methods to legacy models to retrieve related items a bit more efficiently:

```
class Listflower(models.Model):
    especies_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    family_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    especies = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'listflower'

    def get_family(self):
        return FamilyModel.objects.get(family_id=self.family_id)


class Estate(models.Model):
    estate_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    estate_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'estates'

    def get_flowers(self):
        flower_ids = Flower2Estate.objects.filter(estate_id=self.estate_id).values_list('especies_id', flat=True)
        return Listflower.objects.filter(especies_id__in=flower_ids)
```

But if it is not the last time you work with this data probably the better way is to define regular django models with fks and write once a script to convert legacy data to a new model structure. The challenge shouldn't take more than an hour.

**UPDATE**

```
class FlowerFamily(models.Model):
    # assuming you old family model has 
    # "family_id" and "family_name" fields
    family_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    family_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class Flower(models.Model):
    # you might want preserve old model fields in the new model
    # at least id fields
    especies_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    family_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    especies = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    family = models.ForegnKey(FlowerFamily, related_name='flowers')


class NewEstate(models.Model):
    estate_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    estate_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    flowers = models.ManyToManyField(Flower, related_name='estates')




# this is a slightly primitive example
# in real life you might want to use get_or_create instead of direct creation 
# in case script fails and you'll need to run it again
# also objects.get() might better be used with try-except ObjectDoesNotExist
def convert_legacy():
    # create new instances
    for ff in YourOldFamilyModel.objects.all():
        new_ff = FlowerFamily(family_id=ff.family_id, family_name=ff.family_name)
        new_ff.save()

    for fl in Listflower.objects.all():
        new_fl = Flower(...)

        family = FlowerFamily.objects.get(family_id=fl.family_id)

        new_fl.family = family
        new_fl.save()
    
    # same thing for Estate
    for ...:
        new_estate ...
        new_estate.save()

        # and restore relations
        flower_ids = Flower2Estate.objects.filter(estate_id=new_estate.estate_id).values_list('especies_id', flat=True)

        for new_lf in Flower.objects.filter(especies_id__in=flower_ids):
            new_estate.flowers.add(new_fl)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. The db is already loading faster. About the script where do i start, can you give me pointers?

Comment: This is great! doing tests right now, probably gonna use a try catch, i'l update when done THANKS!!